# Visual Studio Code как настроить Debugger

Tags: c, windows, bash, visual-studio-code

Есть VSC Windows настроенный под Си проект для терминала Bash. Make работает, в терминале программа запускается. Но так и не смог найти ответ как настроить отладчик?

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: а отладчик cdb или gdb установлен?

Comment: А VSC это MS Visual C? или что то иное? Если MSVC, то что происходит если нажать кнопку отладка или в коде 'выполнить до текущего места' ?

Comment: @NewView, нет, это вот это: https://code.visualstudio.com/. Заголовки вопросов тоже читать стоит ;)